# What is the better approach for a object trajectory prediction problem with one fixed camera?

Tags: pytorch, computer-vision

These recent days I have been working in a project for an internship I join that mainly works with Computer Vision, and I have been requested for ideas to a project. They want to predict the movements of workers from video frames taken from fixed surveillance cameras.

The main idea to do this is to avoid occupational accidents because of workers that go close to dangerous places or walk by near machinery that could harm them.

The main problem I have faced is that Object Tracking is a task they have already completed, so basically my input is only a bounding box `(x_1, y_1, x_2, y_2)` and I should obtained an immediate prediction within the consecutive 3 or 5 next frames.

My research has mainly one paper:

- [Multiple Object Forecasting: Predicting Future Object Locations in Diverse Environments](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1909.11944.pdf): This paper proposes an architecture that needs Optical Flow, which I do not have access because I only receive the bounding boxes for each frame. This is also used for ego-motion, and the data I receive is from fixed cameras.

So, I came here to ask for your help and know if there is a better approach for the problem I have. If there is more information needed I could provide it.